# Get Scroll Progress of Div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm attempting to write a vue header component that fades in a blurred image overlay from 0 to 1 as the user scroll from the top of the div to the bottom. I can't get this function to work properly for me.

The existing code I have is the following:

```
.header.-standard(:scroll='onScroll()')
  transition(name='fade-in' appear)
    figure
        img(:src="require(`@/assets/img/backgrounds/${background}`)" @load="onBgLoad")
        img.blurred(:src="require(`@/assets/img/backgrounds/${backgroundBlurred}`)")
```

```
props: {
    value: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0.5,
    },
}
data: function() {
    return {
        progress: 0,
    };
},
methods: {
    onScroll() {
        const progress = document.getElementById(this.id).scrollTop / (document.getElementById(this.id).scrollHeight - document.getElementById(this.id).clientHeight);
        if (progress > 1) {
            this.progress = 1;
        } else if (progress < 0) {
            this.progress = 0;
        } else {
            this.progress = progress;
            this.progress = this.value;
        }
        console.log(this.progress);
    },
}
```

Current Output:

The progress data stays at the prop default and never updates, I don't have any console errors.

Comment: first of all, it is not correct to have a `v-else` with no preceding `v-if` or `v-else-if`. Remove the `v-else` and retry

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally left the v-else in as the images are conditional- it still does not work.

Comment: does the onScroll callback fire? if not try listening to scroll on the document body